# How to enable spark UI for Glue Interactive notebooks?

Tags: aws-glue

Is there any way I can enable spark UI (by storing the logs in s3) while running a glue job using interactive notebook?

Comment: have you tried enabling this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-spark-ui-jobs.html on your Glue job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Notebook, you have to add %%configure
{
"--enable-spark-ui": "true",
"--spark-event-logs-path": "s3://path/here"
}